# Display power usage as temperature with Node-Red in Apple HomeKit

Tags: javascript, node-red, homekit, home-automation, ios-homekit

I would like to display the power usage in HomeKit. Unfortunately there is no category to do that in HomeKit. That's why I had the idea to display this not as a power usage but as temperature in HomeKit. The idea is to control HomeKit scenes with the fake temperature sensor.

Unfortunately I have no experience in node-red and it is new for me.

I got the following string from the electricity meter:

```
success: "true"
response: string
{
    "power":    3.040480,
    "relay":    true
}
```

I link this to the HomeKit Node which then returns the following error:

```
Characteristic response cannot be written. 
Try one of these: Name, CurrentTemperature, StatusActive, StatusFault, StatusLowBattery, StatusTampered, Name
```

After various functions and other adjustments I unfortunately don't get the "temperature" displayed in HomeKit.

I use this:
https://flows.nodered.org/node/@plasma2450/node-red-contrib-homekit-bridged

Comment: Where are you defining the service type ? Where is this `Characteristic` key ?

Comment: actually "power" should be displayed as "CurrentTemperature" but my definition does not work. That's why I get the error.
I have tried multiple functions and variables which did not work.

Comment: And where is the definition ? Could we get more code please ? :)

Comment: Currently I don't have a definition for which one works.  As written I tried it with different functions but it doesn't work.

The string I get from the electricity meter I mentioned above.

Answer (score 0):

I think you cannot directly link up the 2 nodes. From the error message it suggests that you have passed the payload from meter output to HomeKit node. While the meter output contains `response` property and it is not supported by HomeKit, your error would occur.

Make sure your payload only consists of the supported Characteristics. You can use a change node to modify the payload, or simply with a a function node

```
const msg.meterOutput = msg.payload;
// Just a prototype, type checking is required
msg.payload = {
    currentTemperature: msg.meterOutput.response.power
}
return msg;
```